# Replace '-' Values in All Columns of Dataframe in For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am scraping several financial metrics from Finviz using a for loop that iterates through a list of stock symbols. I am faced with an issue with the empty values ('-') on Finviz causing issues with subsetting the data down the line, as it is recognized as a string rather than a float, like the values I am trying to subset. I would like to nullify these values and have been trying to use the replace function from the Pandas module, but haven't had any luck. Ideally it nullifies as it iterations the second for loop so that it iterates as it goes rather than having to do it to the entire list after. Code is shown below:

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import numpy as np

# For custom list of stocks, edit this list below, otherwise leave commented out
stock_list = ['NVAX']

# Header required to scrape from Finviz
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
          'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Cookie': 'v2=1495343816.182.19.234.142', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
           'Referer': "http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="}

# This function is what is used to find the metric of interest and return it
def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text

# This function iterates through the index of the data frame (stock_list) and uses the fundemental_metric functinon to find the metric on Finviz for that stock
# Any stock in the list that cannot be scraped will return an error before moving on to the next stock
def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:
            #url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="+ symbol.lower(),headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
            for m in df.columns:
                output = fundamental_metric(soup,m)
                df.loc[symbol,m] = output
                df.replace(['-'], np.NaN)
        except Exception as e:
            print (symbol, 'Not Found')
            print(e)
    return df

# List of metrics to scrape
# Before adding any metrics, ensure the metric being added is available on Finviz and the name is matched identically
metric = [
    'Price'
    , 'Change'
    , 'Index'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(index = stock_list, columns = metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.replace()` is not an inplace operation. You need `df = df.replace()`